# Helm use variable from yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I use a Helm installation for the flipt service. Inside this there is a variable:

```
claimName: {{ default (include "flipt.fullname" .) .Values.persistence.existingClaim }}
```

With this there is an error while create the PVC because the claimName is only `-pvc`and not `flipt-pvc`
If I use the direct way:

```
claimName: "{{ include "flipt.fullname" . }}{{ .Values.persistence.existingClaim }}"
```

The pvc will created well.

```
persistence.existingClaim = "-pvc"

flipt.fullname = "flipt"
```

Any idea why the line with default do not work?

Comment: please add what you're trying to accomplish, and how you assume to use default in your requirement

Comment: In the first example, you have `.Values.persistence.existingClaim` set, and its value is used as-is (the `default` does not need to be applied).  Are you expecting different behavior?